# Cypher: List declared before UNWIND-ing a second list becomes null after UNWIND-ing the second list and executing a MATCH which returns no results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following scenario in a noe4j db:
There are tasks which can be assigned to different users based on some criteria. There's an optional criterion (some tasks have a filter for user's location, some don't).
I need to find all tasks for a user (if they have a location filter, I need to check user's location as well, if they don't I match only by the rest of the criteria).

I've tried to collect the tasks matching the mandatory criteria, then filter those which don't require the optional filter, then filter those which require the optional filter and match the current user and eventually merge the two lists.

Could you also suggest a more efficient way to do this please?

Here's a minimal example (of course, I have more complex matches after UNWIND)

```
WITH [{a: 'test'}, {a: 'a', b: 'b'}] AS initialList

WITH [i IN initialList WHERE i.b IS NULL] AS itemsWithoutB, initialList

UNWIND initialList AS item
MATCH (item) WHERE item.a IS NULL

RETURN COLLECT(item) + itemsWithoutB
```

I would expect here to have the content of `itemsWithoutB` returned, but I get no records (`Response: []`).

Note that if the MATCH done after UNWIND does actually return some records, then the content of `itemsWithoutB` is returned as well.

For example:

```
WITH [{a: 'test'}, {a: 'a', b: 'b'}] AS initialList

WITH [i IN initialList WHERE i.b IS NULL] AS itemsWithoutB, initialList

UNWIND initialList AS item
MATCH (item) WHERE item.a IS NOT NULL

RETURN COLLECT(item) + itemsWithoutB
```

this returns:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"COLLECT(item) + itemsWithoutB"              │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"a":"test"},{"a":"a","b":"b"},{"a":"test"}]│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Neo4j version: enterprise 3.5.6

What am I missing here, please?

**---EDITED---**

I'm adding here a more complex example, closer to the real scenario:

Generate initial data:

```
MERGE (d:Device {code: 'device1', latitude:90.5, longitude: 90.5})-[:USED_BY]->(u:User {name: 'user1'})-[:WORKS_IN]->(c:Country {code: 'RO'})<-[targets:TARGETS]-(:Task {name: 'task1', latitude: 90.5, longitude: 90.5, maxDistance: 1000, maxMinutesAfterLastInRange: 99999})<-[:IN_RANGE {timestamp: datetime()}]-(d)

MERGE (c)<-[:TARGETS]-(:Task {name: 'task2'})

MERGE (c)<-[:TARGETS]-(:Task {name: 'task4', latitude: 10.5, longitude: 10.5, maxDistance: 1, maxMinutesAfterLastInRange: 99999})

CREATE (:User  {name: 'user2'})-[:WORKS_IN]->(:Country {code: 'GB'})<-[:TARGETS]-(:Task {name: 'task3'})
```

Here's a [neo4j console link](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=bc4g4) for this example.

**I want to be able to use the same query to find the tasks for any user (task1 and task2 should be returned for user1, task3 for user2, task4 shouldn't be returned for neither of them)**.

The following query works for user1, but doesn't work if I change the user name filter to "user2":

```
MATCH (user:User {name: "user1"})-[:WORKS_IN]->(country) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (device:Device)-[:USED_BY]->(user)
WITH country, device
MATCH (task:Task)-[:TARGETS]->(country) 
WITH COLLECT(task) AS filteredTasks, device

WITH [t IN filteredTasks WHERE t.latitude IS NULL OR t.longitude IS NULL] AS matchedTasksWithoutLocationFilter, filteredTasks, device

UNWIND filteredTasks AS task
MATCH (device)-[inRange:IN_RANGE]->(task)
WHERE task.maxMinutesAfterLastInRange IS NOT NULL 
AND duration.between(datetime(inRange.timestamp), datetime()).minutes <= task.maxMinutesAfterLastInRange

RETURN COLLECT(task) + matchedTasksWithoutLocationFilter AS matchedTasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer based on new information

I think you can do this in one shot and not need list comprehensions.

```
   MATCH (user: User {name: "user1" })-[:WORKS_IN]->(country)<-[:TARGETS]-(task: Task)
OPTIONAL MATCH (task)<-[inRange: IN_RANGE]-(device: Device)-[:USED_BY]->(user)
    WITH task, inRange
   MATCH (task)
   WHERE (task.latitude IS NULL OR task.longitude IS NULL)
      OR (inRange IS NOT NULL AND 
          task.maxMinutesAfterLastInRange IS NOT NULL AND 
          duration.between(datetime(inRange.timestamp), datetime()).minutes <= task.maxMinutesAfterLastInRange)
  RETURN task
```

For user1:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"task"                                                                │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"task2"}                                                      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"task1","maxDistance":1000,"maxMinutesAfterLastInRange":99999,│
│"latitude":90.5,"longitude":90.5}                                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

For user2:

```
╒════════════════╕
│"task"          │
╞════════════════╡
│{"name":"task3"}│
└────────────────┘
```

### Original answer

When your `MATCH` doesn't return any nodes (in that example, all nodes have an `a` property), the rest of the query's got no work to do - sort of like a failed inner join in a traditional SQL database.

If you switch to an `OPTIONAL MATCH` then you'll see results from `itemsWithoutB` irrespective of whether the `MATCH` worked. I know your example's synthetic so I'm not sure if that's what you're after - in your example the `COLLECT(item)` is going to be working off the `item` from `UNWIND`, and the result of the `OPTIONAL MATCH` is basically irrelevant. Still, imagine that these are real nodes with real queries:

```
WITH [{a: 'test'}, {a: 'a', b: 'b'}] AS initialList
WITH [i IN initialList WHERE i.b IS NULL] AS itemsWithoutB, initialList
UNWIND initialList AS item
OPTIONAL MATCH (item) WHERE item.a IS NULL
RETURN COLLECT(item) + itemsWithoutB
```

You may need to do some further work to de-duplicate the results.

Comment: Thanks @Pablissimo, I've updated my question with a more complex example, more similar to my real scenario.

Comment: The same applies - if you change all the MATCH to OPTIONAL MATCH (aside from the first one for the user) you'll get Task 1 and Task 2 for 'user1', and Task 3 for 'user2'

Comment: Sorry further to that (I've got a recalcitrant toddler who isn't letting me code just now so I can't mock it up...) you might find that a UNION of two queries might both read better and do the de-duplication for you

Comment: I'll give UNION a try as well, thanks for the suggestion.
OPTIONAL would indeed return the expected results here, but the location filter wouldn't actually be applied anymore.
For example, if I add another task named "task4" with location details, but not in range of the user, the query would unexpectedly match that one as well:
`MATCH (c:Country {code: 'RO'})
MERGE (c)<-[:TARGETS]-(:Task {name: 'task4', latitude: 10.5, longitude: 10.5, maxDistance: 1, maxMinutesAfterLastInRange: 99999})`

Comment: I've updated the question with the additional node described in the comment above, which shouldn't be matched at all by the query.

Comment: I understand now I think, and apologies for the bad answering so far - I think the updated answer above should be nearer what you're after?

Comment: It is, indeed. Thanks a lot, @pablissimo